# Discord.py music bot Wavelink error: `TypeError: Type must meet VoiceProtocol abstract base class.`

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, audio-player, voice

The print:

`0|Runa     | <class 'wavelink.player.Player'>`

The error:

```
0|Runa     |     vc:wavelink.Player=await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls= wavelink.Player)
0|Runa     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nextcord/abc.py", line 1683, in connect
0|Runa     |     raise TypeError("Type must meet VoiceProtocol abstract base class.")
0|Runa     | TypeError: Type must meet VoiceProtocol abstract base class.
```

My "play music" command:

```
  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx:commands.Context,*, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
      print(wavelink.Player)
      vc:wavelink.Player=await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls= wavelink.Player)
    elif not ctx.author.voice:
      await ctx.send('Join a voice channel first lol.')
      return
    elif not ctx.author.voice.channel==ctx.voice_client.channel:
      await ctx.send('We need to be in the same voice channel.')
      return
    else:
      vc:wavelink.Player=ctx.voice_client
    if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing():
      await vc.play(search)
      await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {search.title}! {search.uri}')
    else:
      await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
      await ctx.send(f'Added {search.title} to the queue! {search.uri}')
    vc.ctx=ctx
    setattr(vc,'loop',False)
```

The bot sends this error when i use the command `~play link` and does not join vc or play music. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Playing music is no longer allowed through Discord bots using YouTube because it violates YouTubes terms of service.

Comment: I dont know it for sure, but I think nextcord isnt supported by wavelink. Also, please use the tag `nextcord` instead of `discord.py` when using nextcord instead of discord.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to run below for voice support:

Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"

Windows
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]

**this resolved the issue for me.** I'm using nextcord, so used below:

Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U "nextcord[voice]"

Windows

**py -3 -m pip install -U nextcord[voice]**